# in libcurl http/ftp download,how to get the file name in server

Tags: visual-c++, curl, libcurl

I'm tring to write a client for http and ftp download,but i don't know how to get the  filename of the to-be-downloaded url.

Comment: another question is how to distinguish a url from http and ftp?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a url you already have? HTTP urls start with `http:` or `https:`.  FTP urls start with `ftp:` or `ftps:`. As for the filename, do you want to parse the filename out of a url you already have, or do you want to capture the filename that the server sends to you during the download (HTTP only)? Please update your question with more specific details about what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the HTTP Content-Disposition header described by [RFC 6266](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6266.txt)? If that header doesn't come, you have the URL to figure out a file name from.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases:

1. The URL contains filename, for example:

```
https://ntcore.com/files/ExplorerSuite.exe
```

You will extract this name and save the file.

2. The URL does not contain the filename, for example:

```
http://get.adobe.com/reader/download/?installer=Reader_10.1_Basque_for_Windows&standalone=1%22
```

In this case, you can inspect `Content-Disposition` field in HTTP header.

In most cases, you can get the filename this way.